# How to ascii sort a List of User Defined Collection in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a list of collection (objects) where I need to ascii sort them by a specific key (value)
I have tried but all I can find anywhere is a list of strings being ascii sorted instead of objects.
var myList = new List();

And this mylist is as below:

```
[
      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14108,
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14109,
        "value": null
      },

      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14113,
        "value": "1ab"
      },
      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14114,
        "value": "11b"
      },
      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14115,
        "value": "a10"
      },
      {
        "parent": null,
        "Id": 14111,
        "value": "a1234"
      }
    ]
```

I expect the list to be sorted by the value in ascii order but seems a problem only solved by list of strings in c#

Comment: so this is in a list object? how do you put it in that object -- that looks like JSON to me -- which is not C#

Comment: yes, it is just a new List<MyInterfaceObject>();
I just added that just to represent it in a json way

Comment: @VahRun `ascii sort` doesn't mean anything. If you sort by a string, you get lexicographical ordering. If you want localized or customized sorting, you can pass a CultureInfo or StringComparer object as parameter to the Sort or OrderBy methods

Comment: @VahRun check [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings). It explains how culture and culture-invariant sorting works, ordinal comparison (what you probably mean by ASCII sort),  and even how to create your own comparers

Comment: BTW how should `null` be treated? As an empty string? Should it come before or after other rows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an IComparer to your sort method or use a lambda to identify which property should be used to sort. In your example it looks something like `myList.Sort( f => f.value )`

Answer (score 1):

given

```
List<MyInterfaceObject> mylist;
```

then

```
mylist.Sort(x => x.value);
```

Comment: But one question is does it ascii sort?
I need the values to be in ascii and sorted out

Comment: as far as i see, false is higher than true when doing an ascii sort. But it doesnt seem to sort that way.

Comment: @VahRun -- "ascii sort" does  not mean anything to me, it sorts by the default comparer for the field you specify.  If that is a character array and there are only ascii characters in it then yes it does.

Comment: @VahRun -- in your example you have both numberic and string data in the values.  I doubt you will get what you want without a custom sorter in those cases... I've no idea what rules you want for those cases without you explaining your requirements.

Comment: @VahRun -- to explain your requirements show us the code for MyInterfaceObject and be clear about how the value statements you show are loaded into that object.  Then I can tell you how to do what you want.

Comment: the requirement is to sort them based on ascii values event if it is a number or string. If it is a number, we need to cast that to string and then sort them by ascii (i.e. convert them to ascii and sort).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203768/discussion-between-vah-run-and-hogan).

Comment: @VahRun Windows and .NET use Unicode, not ASCII (ie 7-bit, US ASCII). String ordering is lexicographical anyway. If you want ordinal ordering, you can specify it as well.

Comment: @Hogan what the OP calls `ascii sort` may be the ordinal sort, eg `mylist.Sort(x => x.value,StringComparer.Ordinal);`

Comment: yes @PanagiotisKanavos -- I think that is better than `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someString);` which is the more literal meaning of the question